# Managing GameScenes update method and referencing changing instance properties within other classes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, pass-by-reference

I'm making my first game in Swift and I'm trying to get a `SKSpriteNode` subclass instance (`trailingSprite`) to follow or "trail" another `SKSpriteNode` subclass (`User`) that the user controls. I was able to achieve this by making a `move(aUser:User)` method within the `trailingSprite` class that applies a velocity vector to to the trailing body thats the difference of the two `postions` I then call this method inside of GameScenes `Update` function. However, this `trailingSprite` isn't always on screen and can spawn at random times in differing quantities. Is there a more effective way of retrieving "live" or updated positions of the `User` instance within each `trailingSprite` instance instead of having to call a move method for each one inside of Update (which ultimately wont work)? I also tried passing the `User` instance by reference but this still didn't work as the velocity vector never updated from the original positions. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `update` method you should be able to call a move method on every `trailingSprite` in your scene by finding all the nodes with the corresponding name.

```
self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "trailingSprite", using: { node, _ in
    if let trailingSprite = node as? TrailingSprite {
        trailingSprite.move(aUser: user)
    }
})
```

This would require that you set the `name` property on your `TrailingSprite` class:

```
self.name = "trailingSprite"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but does it make sense (from an efficiency standpoint) to keep calling this method though? As of now, the trailing Sprite(s) only become part of the scene towards the end of the game, if at all (they're a boss level of sorts). So I feel as though the method should only be called that frequently if they're definitely on scene- I guess you could use an if statement but I feel as though there should be a way to contain this within the class itself- but I clearly don't know.

Comment: It all depends on your exact game logic, but you could have a boolean variable in your scene that indicates if the trailing nodes are active, and only enumerate your nodes if so. Xcode has a lot of great [performance tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/MeasuringPerformance.html) (especially for SpriteKit), so check those if performance becomes an issue.